# UINavigationController in a UIPopoverController, display title not working

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm not sure why this isn't working as it is working in another area of my app.  I am trying to display the title for the navigationController that is the contentViewController of the popover.  This is the code:

```
        DetailView* details = [[[DetailView alloc] initWithTarget:target] autorelease];
        UINavigationController* content = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:details] autorelease];
        self.popover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content] autorelease];
        [self.popover setDelegate:self];
    }    
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.scrollView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Than in my DetailView.m:

```
- (id)initWithTarget:(Target*)aTarget
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"TargetDetailView" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        target = [aTarget retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Target";
}
```

I have also tried

```
content.navigationItem.title = @"Target";
```

but that does not give me a title in my popover.  Any thoughts?  TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in viewWillAppear:animated

> self.navigationItem.title = @"Target";

I suspect that viewDidLoad is getting called on the DetailView before it is a part of the UINavigationController and therefore it might not have a navigationItem at that time.

Comment: That solved the problem.  Can you explain it more?  I'm curious why it is working this way since I'm doing something very similar somewhere else that works.  The only difference in that situation is that I do initWithNibName when I create that controller, instead of my custom initWithTarget method that calls initWithNibName.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set the `title` property of a `UIViewController`. Once this controller gets picked up into a navigation hierarchy, the `UINavigationController` will read this title into it's own navigation bar. So instead of putting in `viewWillAppear:` to work around the navigation controller, just set it in `-viewDidLoad` and everything will be handled automatically.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Target";
}
```